# File keep recreating itself can't delete[Windows 10]

Tags: windows, github, github-desktop

Have a Windows 10. was working with GitHub Desktop for Windows. After a merge, it created bunch of files with weird names. Merge went good, I deleted all 'weird' files afterwards. But one file **`nrpygtubcm6uc.`** is still in directory. I can't move/delete/rename/open etc that file.

If I try to open a file it says that "file not does not exist". Looks like file recreates itself. Simply put deleted a milisec before any action and recreates.

Tried to use Unlocker(can't delete that file), Windows Defender(doesn't find any viruses) - nothing shows any problem.

Desperate trying to delete it.
Any help if highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It is probably a directory, not a file.  Directories can stay locked when a process has a handle open on it.  Could be the working directory of the process for example.  It disappears automatically when the process releases the handle, typically when it stops running.  Github Desktop is a pretty cranky btw, nothing much to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first what `git status` returns: maybe a simple `git rm yourFile` would be enough.

If not, the file might be considered by Windows as impossible to delete, as [explained by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320081/you-cannot-delete-a-file-or-a-folder-on-an-ntfs-file-system-volume), possibly because of the final '`.`' in its name.

In that case, try the Windows del syntax \?:

```
del \\?\c:\path\to\nrpygtubcm6uc.
```

---

The [OP Oleg Somov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5899916/oleg-somov) mentions [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503906/file-keep-recreating-itself-cant-deletewindows-10/49504513#comment86101906_49504513):

> I managed to delete a folder containing this file using "Unlocker" from IObit.

That is the other cause for a file that keep reappearing: a locked file that a process keeps an handle on.
Try then a git add, commit and push.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wouldn't try to push it to the git, was little scared that this is a virus. Using command you suggested throws me an error "File or path cannot be found". But, I managed to delete a folder containing this file using "Unlocker" from IObit. Should I create an answer to this question and mark it as Answered (or you can edit your answer reflecting the solution)? *Still wondering what the file was that( Git?)?

Comment: @OlegSomov I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. Once the file is removed, you can git add, commit and push: that will record the deletion of that file in the Git repo, both locally and on the remote.